# Names for each plant-based meat type

Tags: vocabulary

The world changes so does the language! I have seen in some vegan restaurant menus, "mylk" refers to non-Dairy milk, which I found pretty interesting and innovative. Out of curiosity, any alternatives to "planet-based beef" (and pork, lamb, chicken)? This is more than just a cool or concise way to refer to these vegan foods. It can also be more accurate, "plant-based beef" is not beef! More accurate is to say "vegan alternative for beef" which is quite long but more accurate.

Comment: Tofurky = tofu turkey substitute, but then that's a brand name

Comment: There's also Beyond Meat and the Impossible Burger, but I don't know that there are any *generic* terms for specific plant based meat substitutes yet

Comment: [*Mylk* is a trademark for a specific brand](https://www.trademarkelite.com/uk/trademark/trademark-detail/UK00913137666/MYLK), not a generic name for plant-based 'milk'.

Comment: @stangdon remember that many trademarks find their way into everyday language as generic concepts.

Comment: @HandsomeNerd True, but I wouldn't want the OP to think they could just use "mylk" in a sentence anywhere and have it be understood.

Comment: @stangdon you cannot assume that for any English word. Like "ephemeral" is a word but you cannot expect everybody or everywhere will understand it. The only difference between "ephemeral" and "mylk" is their birth date! I'm not a fan of "mylk" anyway, as it is a homophone of "milk" and trouble some with verbal communication.